# Writing number with a lot of digits into file using MPIR

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gmp, mpir

I'm using MPIR/Ubuntu 14.04.

I have big integer that have a lot of digits, like 2^1920, and don't know how to write it into file *.txt

```
FILE *result; 

result=fopen("Number.txt","a+");

gmp_fprintf(result,"%d",xyz);

fclose(result);
```

didn't work.

Are there some other options I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`gmp_printf()`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output-Strings.html#Formatted-Output-Strings) function (thus subsequently [`gmp_fprintf()`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output-Functions.html#Formatted-Output-Functions) as well) requires special format specifier for `mpz_t` object (which I guess `xyz` is). You should use `%Zd` instead of plain `%d`, that does not work. To be pedantic it's [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to use inadequate f.s. in C.

If you don't need "full-featured" formatted output, then you might also take a look at [`mpz_out_str()`](https://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Integers.html#I_002fO-of-Integers), that allows to specify base (like 2 or 10):

```
size_t mpz_out_str (FILE *stream, int base, const mpz_t op)
```

Alternatively you might use [`mpz_out_raw()`](https://gmplib.org/manual/I_002fO-of-Integers.html#I_002fO-of-Integers) function that just "dumps" the whole number as it is stored in binary format:

```
size_t mpz_out_raw (FILE *stream, const mpz_t op)
```

> Output op on stdio stream stream, in raw binary format. The integer is
>   written in a portable format, with 4 bytes of size information, and
>   that many bytes of limbs. Both the size and the limbs are written in
>   decreasing significance order (i.e., in big-endian).